# Deploying a VueJs + Node app on App Engine w/ CloudBuild

Tags: node.js, vue.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

My project is a VueJS frontend + Node Backend. The project is organized like this:

```
  /api (all the backend logic, like uploading to GCS)
    package.json
  /ui (all front end logic)
    package.json
  /config
    cloudbuild.yaml
  app.yaml
```

My specific issue is that when the project is built, only the vue-cli portion of the project is built and deployed. The Node logic is not. What steps do I need to add to my cloudbuild or app.yaml files to ensure that the Node logic is being built and deployed along with the frontend code?

Here is my cloudbuild.yaml file for reference

```
//cloudbuild.yaml 
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud:latest
  entrypoint: "ls"
  args: ["-lah","/workspace"]
  dir: "api"
- name: node
  entrypoint: yarn
  args: ["install"]
  dir: "api"
- name: node
  entrypoint: yarn
  args: ['run', 'build']
  dir: "api"
- name: node
  entrypoint: yarn
  args: ["install"]
  dir: "ui"
- name: node
  entrypoint: yarn
  args: ['add', '@vue/cli']
  dir: "ui"
- name: node
  entrypoint: yarn
  args: ['run', 'build']
  dir: "ui"
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy", "./app.yaml"]
timeout: "1600s"
```

Here is my app.yaml file for reference

```
//app.yaml
runtime: nodejs14
service: icx-ui
handlers:
  # Serve all static files with urls ending with a file extension
- url: /(.*\..+)$ 
  static_files: ui/dist/\1
  upload: ui/dist/(.*\..+)$
  # catch all handler to index.html
- url: /.*
  static_files: ui/dist/index.html
  upload: ui/dist/index.html
```

Comment: Do you want to deploy 2 services? Or only 1 with the 2 dirs in the same service? What is your issue for now?

Comment: I would like to deploy 1 project with the 2 dirs in the same service. One directory would be the front end, and the other the backend/API. I realized that I wasn't building the backend service in my Cloudbuild file, so I'm using webpack, but any other direction would be useful

Comment: What is and where is the packages.json file for your backend service?

Comment: There are two package.jsons: one found under the `/ui` directory that is specific to VueJS and the other under the `/api` directory that is specific to Node

Comment: ok, and what is the URL path for the backend service? In your app.yaml you serve only static content on any URL path `/.*`

Comment: Oh, should those be defined? For example: the call that goes to `/api/upload/` from the front end should be defined in the app.yaml for the front end?

Comment: You must define that the url path (pattern) that reach the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the directory of your backend logic from `ui` to `api`:

from:

```
- name: node
  entrypoint: yarn
  args: ['run', 'build']
  dir: "ui"
```

to:

```
- name: node
  entrypoint: yarn
  args: ['run', 'build']
  dir: "api"
```

Comment: This failed because I need to build both the `/ui` and `/api`. I've edited my original question with the new `cloudbuild.yaml` file